# Is it possible to explicitly instantiate a function with the body, defined within a template definition?

Tags: c++, templates

Let's consider the following code:

```
#include<iostream>

class A
{
public:
    template<class T>
    void foo(T t){ std::cout << "foo()" << std::endl; }
};

template<> void A::foo<int>(int t);
template<> void A::foo<A*>(A* t);

int main(){ A a; a.foo(5); };
```

**[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/439c1992c9fcb7f3)**

For instance, I just want to explicitly provide two definitions as I defined in the function template body for the instantiated functions. Is it possible to do that with explicit instantiation or the only way to do that is implicit instantiation?

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to do and you r example does not explain it at all. You call it "explicit instantiation", but it looks like you are actually talking about *explicit specialization*. *Explicit specialization* and *explicit instantiation* are two completely different things. So, one more time: what do you want to happen in your example?

Comment: @AnT Could you possibly provide the link about a defect that you provided as a coment to Mike's post? I couldn't follow it.

Comment: @Dmitry Fucintv: There's an open defect that says that the syntax of *explicit instantiation* is too permissive http://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#293 . So far it was based on the fact that "everybody understood" that including a function body (or an initiaizer etc.) into explicit instantiation makes no sense. (I hope they tighten up the definition in the future.) Anyway, why would you want to do that? Are you asking an abstract question about the standard? If so, then you can find peace in the above defect, which agrees that the issue exists: the definition is too loose.

Comment: @Dmitry Fucintv: You are not supposed to be able to specify function body in *explicit instantiation* syntax. That would make no sense. But the standard apparently "forgot" to prohibit it, unless I missed some other place in the text that prohibits it.

Comment: @AnT Your explanation is exactly what I wsa looking for. Thank you, now it's perfectly clear.